# Problem passing array items onto a forEach loop in googlesheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, foreach

I'm trying to pass data from cells in google sheets to access information from other sheets.

Firstly I saved my google sheets ids as an array as well as the sheet names.

However, when I tried to pass the array of items into a forEach loop, it only selects the first array object.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    function retrieveData(ssA, ssB) {

        var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 3, 4, 1);
        var sourceSpreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 4, 4, 1);
        ssA.forEach(function(ssA) {
            var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA);
            sourceSpreadsheetName.forEach(function(sourceSpreadsheetName) {
                var ss = sss.getSheetByName(sourceSpreadsheetName);
                var SRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 2);
                var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
                var SData = SRange.getValues();
                var ssB = '1Dp1dOcwaup184mt1zWU-lcA5Nw-jFguWrr_H2hrtKSg';
                var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssB);
                var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Customers need to contact');
                ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
                Logger.log(ssA + sourceSpreadsheetName);
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: I find it confusing to name the variable in the forEach function the same thing as the name of the array. If you change `ssA.forEach(function(ssA) { ... }` to
`ssA.ForEach(function(s) { ... }` does the problem still exist?

Comment: hey yes it does it sends  a message saying bad value

Comment: @Renier Can you provide the detail information about `it sends a message saying bad value`? And in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you update the script in your question to the current one?

Comment: I tried it again.  The problem seems to be that it loops over the each of the array items four times . So instead of four sheets sixteen sheets are being passed through. I wonder if it is due to a forEach loop is nested in another one. However I can't process them seperately because i need  to use a variable in the first loop's scope to execute the rest of the code.